# My methods will not talk and return value to use

Tags: c#, class, oop

I must first work with the class to my website after which have seen some videos.

It is such that I must use this value here several times since, but instead of fumbling through multiple files to the right so I just had to go into a file in order to do it.

My class:

```
public class point
{
    int pointBrugerVis = 250;

    public static string VisPoint()
    {
        return pointBrugerVis;
    }
}
```

My class is called like this:

```
LabelPointVis.Text = point.VisPoint();
```

I immediately see this error:

**An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'point.pointBrugerVis'**

Comment: You *may* want `static int pointBrugerVis = 250;` but then you might be better to remove `static` and then make an instance of point. It depends on your usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear enough: pointBrugerVis is not a **static** field.

Also note that VisPoint() is returning a string... and pointBrugerVis is an integer.

```
static int pointBrugerVis = 250;

public static string VisPoint()
{
    return pointBrugerVis.ToString(); // Or change the method's return type
}
```

Alternatively:

```
int pointBrugerVis = 250;

public string VisPoint()
{
    return pointBrugerVis.ToString();
}
```

Which you'd then make an instance of with:

```
point p = new point();
LabelPointVis.Text = p.VisPoint();
```

Comment: Thakns for help! :) i hope u giv me +1 for its question

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
public static String pointBrugerVis = "250";
```

and change you return type from string to String;

a better way of dealing with constant is to declare like

```
public static final String POINT_BRUGER_VIS = "250";
```

and call by point.POINT_BRUGER_VIS

btw, you should uppercase your class

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the static keyword, to be able to do the following

```
    public class point
    {
        int pointBrugerVis = 250;

        public string VisPoint()
        {
            return pointBrugerVis.ToString();
        }
    }
```